# Dependent 2 queries on "same" column in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I have a table like below

```
report_code | result_of_report
_______________________________
Rpx-34512-00| rejected
Rpx-34512-01| rejected
Rpx-34512-02| rejected
Rpt-22433-00| rejected
Rpt-22433-01| rejected
Rpt-22433-02| rejected
Rpt-22433-03| rejected
Rpt-22433-04| rejected
Rpt-22433-05| rejected
Rpt-22433-06| accepted
Rcs-34555-00| rejected
Rcs-34555-01| rejected
Rcs-34555-02| accepted
```

And this is what I want to get: For `report_code` I need to `substr(report_code, 4,5)` to 5 digit report code and look for reports that haven't yet accepted.

6th revision (it doesn't matter which version accepted btw.) of `22433` has a record of accepted. So it passed. `34555` get accepted in second revision. It passed too. BUT `34512` doesn't have any accepted record. I want to list all records like `34512` but with groups. So I don't want to list many duplicated line. To make it more clear, no need to list `34512` 3 times. One will be enough.

First of all I want to explain what I tried. I know it doesn't the right way but it was a temporary solution for me.

I ran a loop to take `where result_of_report='rejected'` and inside this loop, I took that 5 digit report_code as `$code` and I used that code in a loop as `where(report_code, 'like', '$code) AND where(result_of_report, '=', 'accepted')` inside of the first one to make query for every record. ‍♂️

As you can see, it's not the right way but also I don't know the right way too. I'm open to any idea to make it in a most efficient way. Don't want to make millions of loop iteration. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: It's better than long explanations, sample data and expected output

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could group by `SUBSTR(report_code, 5,5)` and use conditional aggregation as the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(report_code, 5,5) AS report_code
FROM table_name
GROUP BY SUBSTR(report_code, 5,5)
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN result_of_report='accepted' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

`HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN result_of_report='accepted' THEN 1 END) = 0` is used to ensure that there is at least one row with `result_of_report='accepted'`. Note that the count function counts only not null values, so rows with `result_of_report<>'accepted` will not count.

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ctE4cRd3).

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Works like charm. Can you please explain last line to understand it better.

Comment: @VitoAndolini the last line could be written easier as *HAVING SUM(result_of_report = 'accepted') = 0*.  In simple words if one of the `SUBSTR(report_code, 5,5)` has the value of the result_of_report='accepted' it will be excluded by the end result, it must have all the values equal to rejected per each group

Comment: @ErgestBasha, thank you for this contribution.

Comment: @VitoAndolini, I edited the answer to include extra clarification.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` along with aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(report_code, '-', 2), '-', -1) AS report_code
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY 1
HAVING SUM(result_of_report = 'accepted') = 0;
```